# Spring boot project can't start [Kotlin]

Tags: spring, kotlin

Intellij idea cannot run a project written in Kotlin, because it adds **kt** to the file name in Run/debug.
The same project on another device runs, but this one gives an error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class <path>.ServiceApplicationKt Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: <path>.ServiceApplicationKt`

The project is written in Java 11.

[Run/debug Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rt3B.png)

I tried reinstalling the IDE, resetting the cache and reloading Gradle. I reinstalled Java, but no result.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.

1. Click File>Settings.
   [image]
2. Go to Build, Execution, Deployment > Maven > Gradle.
   [image]

As for me, the inside of the red square was both set to Gradle like the picture above.

3. Change both to 'IntelliJ IDEA' as shown in the picture.
   [image]

It worked for me.